# Tablesorter Custom Parser Commas Not Working?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following jQuery to sort a table:

```
jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: 'fancyNumber',
  is: function (s) {
    return /^[0-9]?[0-9,\.]*$/.test(s);
  },
  format: function (s) {
    return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(/,/g, ''));
  },
  type: 'numeric'
});
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#<%=gvReport.ClientID%>").tablesorter();
});
```

However, the custom parser is not sorting numbers with commas correctly.  It's treating them as strings.  I've applied the CSS class to my header cell like so:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-CssClass="green" 
    FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-CssClass="green" 
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="green {sorter: 'fancyNumber'}" HeaderStyle-Width="4.55%">

    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblHForecast_total" Text="Forecast" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblForecast_total" Text='<%#Eval("f_total", "{0:#,###,0}")%>' runat="server" CssClass="txtBoldSmall"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFForecast_total" CssClass="txtBoldSmall">
        </asp:Label>
     </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Note that I'm adding the `{sorter: 'fancyNumber'}` to the CSS class of the `<th>` I want to sort.  It is applied correctly, as evidenced by Chrome's Inspector:

[image]

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: So, your numbers greater than 999 are using comma separators for the thousands' place?

Comment: try `{sorter:digit}` instead of `{sorter:fancyNumber}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up explicitly defining the columns for the 'fancyNumber' sort in the jQuery call as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: 'fancyNumber',
        is: function(s) {
            return /^[0-9]?[0-9,\.]*$/.test(s);
        },
        format: function(s) {
            return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(/,/g, ''));
        },
        type: 'numeric'

    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#<%=gvReport.ClientID%>").tablesorter({
            headers: {
                2:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                3:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                4:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                5:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                6:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                7:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                8:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                9:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                10:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                11:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                12:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                13:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                14:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                15:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                16:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                17:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                18:{sorter:'fancyNumber'},
                19:{sorter:'fancyNumber'}
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```